# What is the relationship between sequences and series?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

If I am given a sequence  made up of positive real numbers, and I know the series $\sum{M_n}$ converges, what can I say about M<sub>n</sub>?
I am trying to prove that M<sub>n</sub> converge. I know it has something to do with the relationship between series and sequences.

Comment: A series is a special type of sequence, namely, the sequence of partial sums of another sequence.

Comment: How would I use that though in this problem?

Comment: Let me give you a hint: [The Limit Comparison Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly say that $\lim_{n\to\infty} M_n = 0$ (see the first line of "Proofs" [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test#Proofs)). That's not sufficient, but it's hard to write a truly general statement that all such sequences satisfy.